# How split a string left to the second delimiter from the right and there is special character in delimiter?

Tags: sql, string, split

I have a field with full address line is supposed to be delimited by line feed '
'like below

```
    Primary_Address_-_Full
    3903 NE 45th Street&#xa;APT 204&#xa;Seattle, WA 98105&#xa;
    20504 NE 21st Ct.&#xa;Sammamish, WA 98074&#xa;
    219 W Callender St&#xa;# A2-2&#xa;Livingston, MT 59047&#xa;
    102 Branegan Ct&#xa;Unit A&#xa;Bozeman, MT 59715&#xa;
    8923 Ravenna Ave NE&#xa;Seattle, WA 98115&#xa;
```

What I want to have in results is anything before the second '
' from the right end, literally before the city name.  I don't worry about the left '
' in the results strings although it is better without them, since I can always replace it later.

Results would be like:

```
    Primary_Address
    3903 NE 45th Street&#xa;APT 204
    20504 NE 21st Ct.
    219 W Callender St
    102 Branegan Ct&#xa;Unit A
    8923 Ravenna Ave NE
```

I tried split function but it didn't provide the desired results. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Are you looking for a sql solution? If you which platform?

Comment: Yes, SQL Server Management Studio 10

Comment: Generally, I am looking for anything left of the second instance of &#xa; from the right

Comment: I feel it like substring_index for MySQL with negative count 2, and return the left of the substring_index results. Is it the right way of thinking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by serially locating the character and adding the string length segments together. Its a bit of a hack and could be better done in regex outside of the db I think.

```
select left(value,
   len(value) - (charindex(char(10), reverse(value)) + 
   charindex(char(10), substring(reverse(value), charindex(char(10), 
   reverse(value))+1, len(value))))) 
from  
   (select replace(YourField, '&#xa;', char(10)) as value from test2) x;
```

You could also amend the outer query with another replace to return the remaining linefeeds to '&#xa;'

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the results string is left of first two linefeeds like 3903 NE 45th Street&#xa;APT 204& 20504 NE 21st Ct.&#xa;Sammamish, WA 98074. What I am looking for is string left to the last two linefeeds, basically no city names are included. Appreciate it

Comment: for me, it returns the original strings :(

Comment: I tried select top 100 left([Primary_Address_-_Full],
        len([Primary_Address_-_Full]) - (charindex('&#xa;', reverse([Primary_Address_-_Full])) + 
           charindex('&#xa;', substring(reverse([Primary_Address_-_Full]), 
           charindex('&#xa;', reverse([Primary_Address_-_Full]))+1, len([Primary_Address_-_Full]))))),[Primary_Address_-_Full]
 from [WDHRISods].[WD].[Personal]
 where [Primary_Address_-_Full] is not null

Comment: I wonder if its the character matching. Can you use `char(10)` instead of `'&#xa;'`?

Comment: tried, the string runs with the same result.   select top 100 left([Primary_Address_-_Full],
        len([Primary_Address_-_Full]) - (charindex(char(10), reverse([Primary_Address_-_Full])) + 
           charindex(char(10), substring(reverse([Primary_Address_-_Full]), 
           charindex(char(10), reverse([Primary_Address_-_Full]))+1, len([Primary_Address_-_Full]))))),[Primary_Address_-_Full]
 from [WDHRISods].[WD].[Personal]
 where [Primary_Address_-_Full] is not null

Comment: There got to be an issue with character matching. You can try just `charindex(char(10), Primary_Address-Full)` to see if its matching anything at all

Comment: select charindex('&#xa;', [Primary_Address_-_Full])
 
  from [WDHRISods].[WD].[Personal]
  where [Primary_Address_-_Full] is not null return position but char(10) return all zero results

Comment: might be the reverse? I need to reverse the '&#xa;'? working thanks.   select top 100 left([Primary_Address_-_Full],
        len([Primary_Address_-_Full]) - (charindex(';ax#&', reverse([Primary_Address_-_Full])) + 
           charindex(';ax#&', substring(reverse([Primary_Address_-_Full]), 
           charindex(';ax#&', reverse([Primary_Address_-_Full]))+1, len([Primary_Address_-_Full]))))),[Primary_Address_-_Full]
 from [WDHRISods].[WD].[Personal]
 where [Primary_Address_-_Full] is not null

Comment: Oh I see whats happening I think. You have the entity in there as a replacement for line feed, its not interpreted as a character. I would suggest trying to replace value in the above query with `replace(value, '&#xa;', char(10))` which will make for a very convoluted expression but may work. Using a temp table as an intermediate is probably a good idea here too, it depends on what you are ultimately trying to accomplish

Comment: I actually made it work by reversing delimiter '&#xa;' to ';ax#&' since the delimiter characters are reversed with the whole string under reverse function. Thank you for your help and inspiration

Comment: I amended the answer to replace the string with a single character as another alternative. 
Glad to help.